# Asterisk and Sipp UAS

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip, sip-server

I'm trying to get sipp communicate with Asterisk in order to perform
performance tests:

I've been through these steps:

1) In sip.conf

```
[sippuac]
type=friend
username=sippuac
host=127.0.0.1
port=5061
context=test
dtmfmode=rfc2833
insecure=very
canreinvite=no
nat=yes

[sippuas]
type=friend
username=sippuas
host=127.0.0.1
port=5062
context=test
dtmfmode=rfc2833
insecure=very
canreinvite=no
nat=yes
```

2) In extensions.conf

```
[test]
exten=>s,1,Dial(SIP/sippuas,20)
```

3) Running SIPp

```
sipp -sn uas -rsa 127.0.0.1:5060 -p 5062 -i 127.0.0.1 -mp 6001

sipp -sn uac 127.0.0.1:5060 -s s -p 5061 -i 127.0.0.1
```

Finally I get on Asterisk :

> [Jun 14 07:36:56] WARNING[2600][C-00000120]: app_dial.c:2437
>   dial_exec_full: Unable to create channel of type 'SIP' (cause 20 -
>   Subscriber absent)

How can I solve this and make the UAS receive the calls ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Debug is offtopic on SO. Check firewall, check "sip show peers" on asterisk

Answer (score 0):

I think in sip.conf should be type=peer for sippuas.

It is bad idea to run performance test from localhost. SIPP will impact performance of Asterisk. Additionally it make seance to run scenario with audio and I will recommend just answer a call on Asterisk and play some sound, it is not so important to send call out to second sipp.

Answer (score 0):

For receiving calls from asterisk, SIPp user(s) should be registered first to it. You can see if your user is registered or not by using the command:

```
sip show peers
```

in the asterisk CLI. If your uas is not registered and you are trying to tell asterisk to dial to a client and not giving the address of it. There are simple xml examples in this [link](http://tomeko.net/other/sipp/sipp_cheatsheet.php?lang=en) for how to register and make calls to asterisk. Please follow the scenario you want.